# Best way to get Excel to sample an array

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have been trying to figure out how to use excel to select a value from a grid based on three conditions. The grid is below

Say I have the following

| A | B | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0.1 | 40 | 30 | 20 |
| 0.1 | 0.5 | 10 | 20 | 30 |

If I had a value (X), say X =  0.2, I would like Excel to determine which row of the grid to sample by placing it within a range A and B. So for this example, it would be row 2 (as 0.5 is between 0.1 and 0.5). Based on another condition, (say Z) it would select one of the "1,2,3" columns to select a value. So for example with X = 0.5 and Z = 2, the result would be 20.

I have been playing around for a long time, and I cannot seem to do it. I know how to do it using VBA (or even Python), but I want to use basic excel functions.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thanks Scott. How would you select the row based on a range? Match has either Less than, equal to, greater than, with no <= or >=

Comment: Match will look in Column A and find the relative match.  As long as there are no gaps it will find where it fits.

Comment: If there are no gaps you only need the start and not the end.

Comment: Absolute legend! works perfectly. Thanks Scott.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or, use Lookup + Index

```
=LOOKUP(G1,A2:A3,INDEX(C2:E3,0,H1))
```

[image]

Comment: Just one note for future readers on this: This works when the titles are numbers and in order and match their relative column number, otherwise a match like the second match from my answer would need to replace the `H1` in this answer.  This works with the data of the OP and is a good option, so this note is only for those future readers.

Answer (score 2):

Use INDEX and 2 MATCHes

```
=INDEX($A$1:$E$3,MATCH(G1,$A:$A),MATCH(H1,$1:$1,0))
```

[image]